# FOR COUNTER loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to make this for loop output the first ten squares (1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100). I am kind of new to this. Can someone help?

```
FOR x=0  until  x >= 5   x++
{
Display x;
}
```

I have this, but I need the square of a number from 1-10.
And then I need a WHILE Loop with the square of a number from 1-10

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. Do you want the program to print out 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100?

Comment: just pseudocode. Doesn't have to be exactly right. Just close to it

Comment: Patrick, can you show me what you mean?

Comment: He's asking if the output should be 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100.

Comment: I know that, I mean in code terms

Comment: Well, what's the answer?

Comment: ikegami, can you explain what yours means?

Comment: Still waiting for an answer from *you*

Comment: Should the output should be 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100 (the first ten squares)?

Comment: Yes, the output should be 1, 4, 9, 25, 49, 64, 81, 100

Comment: how about `FOR x=1  until  x = 10   x++
{
Display x * x;
}`

Comment: Exactly which part are you have a problem with? Looping from 1 to 10 instead of from 0 to 4 (just change the 0 and 5)? Indicating that you're multiplying a number with itself (`x*x`?)? Something else?

Comment: @kiruwka Actually that typically wouldn't run the loop for `x = 10` (at least in most / all languages I know, so most would assume pseudocode to behave similarly). You'd need something like `while x <= 10` or `until x > 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal set of changes to your code would create this:

```
FOR x=0  until  x >= 10   x++
{
    Display (x + 1) * (x + 1);
}
```

Note the changes:

1. Changed `x >= 5` to `x >= 10`. If you want to output 10 things, the upper bound needs to be 10, not 5.
2. Changed `Display x` do `Display (x + 1) * (x + 1)`. Here, `+` means addition and `*` means multiplication. This change is needed to get the output `1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100`.

Note also that other changes are possible which give the same results; a good alternative might be:

```
FOR x=1  until  x >= 11   x++
{
    Display x * x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is pseudo language.

This code fragment will loop from 1 to 10 and output the squares of each number.

Output:
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100

while loop:

```
i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
  echo i*i;
  i++;
}
```

for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  echo i*i;
}
```

Comment: Can you convert this to a FOR Loop also?

Comment: Note that this is close, but doesn't quite work since you also print out 0. I know, I know, pedantic - but, for the record, it wasn't me that down-voted you.

Comment: Thanks for the help and also the practice.. Elaborating helped me out a lot

Answer (score 0):

The square of a number of is just itself multiplied by itself.

```
for my $n (1..10) {
   my $square = $n * $n;
   print("$square\n");
}
```

Comment: I don't like this answer from several reasons. (1) I don't like 'code only' answers, without verbal explanation. (2) I believe that when the OP has posted a code, an answer should minimally change it in order to provide the answer. (3) I have no idea what language it is, but the `while(1)` is a bad practice for beginners in most languages, and the OP obviously is a beginner.

Comment: @amit, 1) you really want me to say what `=` and `*` do!? 2) That's nice. But that require knowing how many squares there is in a range of integers, which far from trivial to do because of rounding errors! I opted for the straightforward solution. 3) How is `while (1)` a bad practice?!

Comment: (1) no, I want you to say "you should just display something else rather than `x`. You can use the `operator*` to achieve it (or something similar). (2) There are other ways, like changing the condition... (3) while(true) and using only early termination leads to [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) for novice developers. A better practice is usually `while (cond)`, and not using `break` (or smilar) statements to abort the loop.

Comment: @amit, 1) That communicates absolutely no information. 2) I disagree, using code that doesn't work with NOT a better practice. // Anyway, this is moot. The OP clarified that he wanted something else.